# Using REG QUERY to return only a value of a registry key

Tags: batch-file, registry

I'm writing a batch file that executes certain exes in a specified folder.
The fact is that the directory of these files is not always the same so I need to read the registry key to set the correct path in a variable.
I'm doing this with

```
REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SOMETHING" /v "Path exe"
```

And I get this output:

```
Path exe    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\PROGRAM FOLDER
```

Is there any way to return **only** `C:\Program Files (x86)\PROGRAM FOLDER` **without** `Path exe` and `REG_SZ`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window and type `for /?`, then find the `/F` option…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example to query the Path of ***7-zip*** :

---

```bat
@echo off
@FOR /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('Reg Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\7-Zip" /v "Path" 2^>Nul') do Set "ExePath=%%j"
If defined ExePath (echo EXEPATH="%ExePath%" ) Else ( echo EXEPATH NOT FOUND !!!)
pause

@FOR /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('Reg Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\7-Zip" /v "Path32" 2^>Nul') do Set "ExePath32=%%j"
If defined ExePath32 (echo EXEPATH32="%ExePath32%" ) Else ( echo EXEPATH32 NOT FOUND !!!)
pause
Exit /B
```

---

Another Example for ***VLC*** :

---

```bat
@echo off
@FOR /f "tokens=3*" %%i in ('Reg Query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VideoLAN\VLC /ve 2^>Nul') do Set "VLCPathEXE=%%j"
If defined VLCPathEXE (echo VLCPathEXE="%VLCPathEXE%") Else (echo VLCPathEXE NOT FOUND !!!)
pause
```

Comment: Tacchino Robot, using just `tokens=2*` or `Tokens=2,*` only works when it is certain that the registry value does not contain a space or tab delimiter. Just `tokens=3*` or `Tokens=3,*` only works when the registry value contains exactly two tokens split by one or more spaces and/or tabs. It is essential therefore that you adjust your code 'tokens' each time based upon the known registry value string.